# I can not use the clipboard, I want to share text between local and remote machine. What do I need to do to fix this?

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-server-2012, remote-server, remote-desktop

I can not use the clipboard, I want to share text between local and remote machine. What do I need to
do to fix this?

Comment: Is a process called `rdpclip.exe` running inside the computer you are trying to connect to? If not, did you attempt to start it (it should be at `C:\Windows\System32\rdpclip.exe`)?

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of clipboard sharing between local machine and Remote Machine.

1. text. You need to enable the Clipboard redirect in the Local Resource of MSTSC.exe before inital the Remote Session.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhPtm.jpg)

2. Clipboard file copy redirection. To allow the file copy redirection, you need to enable "Clipboard" redirction in MSTSC.exe, and do not enable the policy named "Do not allow drive redirection".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6x6OF.jpg)